# Integral with partial fractions algebra problem

Tags: calculus

I am calculating an integral, which requires me to use partial fractions, however I am caught up in the algebra.

$\int\frac{x^4 -5x^3 + 6x^2 -18}{x^3 -3x^2}dx$

$\int(x-2) +\frac{-18}{x^3 -3x^2}dx$

$\int(x-2) +\frac{-18}{x^3}-\frac{18}{-3x^2}dx$

$\int(x-2) -\frac{18}{x^3}+\frac{18}{3x^2}dx$

Check:

$\frac{x^4-5x^3+6x^2-18}{x^3-3x^2}$ = (x-2) + $\frac{-18}{x^3-3x^2}$

$\frac{x^4-5x^3+6x^2-18}{x^3-3x^2}$ =  $\frac{(x-2)(x^3-3x^2)}{(x^3-3x^2)}$ + $\frac{-18}{x^3-3x^2}$

$\frac{x^4-5x^3+6x^2-18}{x^3-3x^2}$ = $\frac{x^4-3x^3-2x^3+6x^2}{x^3-3x^2}$ + $\frac{-18}{x^3-3x^2}$

With some algebra we end up with what we started with.

$\frac{x^4-5x^3+6x^2-18}{x^3-3x^2}$ = $\frac{x^4-5x^3+6x^2-18}{x^3-3x^2}$

Ideally, I want to turn the two fractions into a form where I can take the natural log when I integrate, but I am lacking on some fundamental algebra skills. If anyone could explain how to convert them into a $\frac {1}{x}$ form I would appreciate it.

Comment: you don't need to convert them to $\frac{1}{x}$ form. I will show.

Comment: Right, but I think I just figured out the problem. I forgot that I needed to take $\frac{-18}{x^3 - 3x^2}$ and put it into the form $\frac{A}{x}$ + $\frac{B}{x}$ or something.

Comment: no. your expression $\frac{-18}{x^3 - 3x^2}$ has a cubic denominator. It cannot be expressed like you said.

Comment: Your factoring is wrong btw. May I show you how to integrate the whole thing from the very beginning?

Comment: Sure, but I'm confident it's right. I'll post my check and you post yours.

Comment: Since the degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator, perform long division and *then* seek a partial fraction decomposition for the remainder.

Comment: @JohnD Yeah, that's how I got (x-2) + $\frac{-18}{x^3-3x^2}$

Comment: @StarCute that isn't called partial fraction. At least that is only half of the work. See my answer.

Comment: $${-18\over x^3-3x^2}={-18\over x^3}-{18\over-3x^2}???$$ Ouch! The problem isn't partial fractions, it's fractions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factoring is wrong. This is how you should do it.

$$\int\frac{x^4 -5x^3 + 6x^2 -18}{x^3 -3x^2}\,dx = $$

$$\int(x-2) +\frac{-18}{x^3 -3x^2}\,dx$$

as you correctly observe.

$$=\int(x-2)\,dx -18\int\frac{dx}{x^3-3x^2} \tag{1}$$

The first integral is easy and equal to $\frac{x^2}{2} - 2x+ c$. I am assuming you know how to do this.

Now the second integral,

$$\int\frac{18\,dx}{x^3-3x^2}= \int\frac{18\,dx}{x^2(x-3)}$$

We can express $$\frac{18}{x^2(x-3)} = \frac{A}{x-3} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2}$$

and not $\frac{A}{x} - \frac{B}{x}$ as you state in your comment.

Taking the right hand side to a common denominator,

$$\frac{18}{x^2(x-3)} = \frac{Ax^2+ Bx^2 + Cx - 3Bx - 3C}{x^2(x-3)} $$

Comparing both sides of the equation,

$A+B=0 \text{ (coefficient of $x^2$ must be zero)}$
$C-3B=0$
$-3C=18$

which gives us, $A=2,B=-2,C=-6$

Thus,

$$\frac{18}{x^2(x-3)} = \frac{2}{x-3} + \frac{-2x-6}{x^2}$$

Substituting back into our original integral

$$\int (x-2)\,dx -\int\frac{2\,dx}{x-3} +\int\frac{2\,dx}{x}+\int\frac{6\,dx}{x^2}$$

Integrate each term by term, using the formula

$$\int x^n\,dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + c,\,\,n\ne -1$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(x)+c$$

Comment: Check: $\frac{x^2}{2}$ -2x + 2ln(x-3) - 2ln(1-x) -6ln(x)

Comment: The parens should be absolute values.

Comment: @StarCute I think you made a typo in the second last term. It should be $-2\ln(x)$

Comment: the last term is $$\int 6x^{-2}\,dx = \frac{6x^{-1}}{-1}$$Other than that, you're correct.

Comment: My mistake. Okay, thank you very much. You have been more than helpful.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: Did you make a sign error when substituting back into the integral? It should be +$\int\frac{2dx}{x}$ - $\int\frac{6dx}{x^2}$ correct?

Comment: @StarCute Well I don't *see* any error. Which term?

Comment: @StarCute oh no. the original integral was $$-\int\frac{18}{x^2(x-3)}$$

Comment: That's my bad. You're right :)

Comment: @StarCute There is indeed a sign error in the above partial fraction calculation. The numerator should be $-18$ not $18$.

Comment: @BillDubuque there is no error. I multiplied the minus when substituting back.

Comment: @Sabyasachi The displayed partial fraction expansion of $\,18/(x^2(x-3))$ has **two sign errors**.

Comment: @BillDubuque wait what? *two*? which?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Do the arithmetic. Please fix it.

Comment: $$\frac{18}{x^2(x-3)} = \frac{-2}{x-3} + \frac{2x-6}{x^2}$$ are you referring to this line? It seems right.

Comment: oh wait. no. got it.